How to Isolate $P$ in the Logarithmic Equation $P = a \log\left(\frac{s + z\times P}{s + y \times P}\right) + c$?
Given the equation $P = a \log\left(\frac{s + z \times P}{s + y \times P}\right) + c$, where $a, c, s, z$, and $y$ are positive constants and $P$ is a positive variable, I need to isolate $P$ so that it can be calculated based on the other constants. Is there a method to isolate $P$, or can it be demonstrated that this is not possible?

You mention a constant $N$ but it is not in the equation. Where does $N$ come into play?

@Nelewout You are right, I had absorbed it into other constants and had forgotten to remove it. I just revised it.

Is a numerical algorithm for computing $P$ sufficient, or do you need an analytic solution (a formula for $P$ in terms of the constants)? I think the latter is unlikely.

@prubin I am looking for an analytical solution, but approximation also works. Thanks! I have tried the second order of Taylor series expansion and the accuracy is not bad. Is there any other approximation technique I can apply?

There are quite a few iterative methods to find $P$. A very simple one that seems to work (at least on a few test cases I tried) is averaging. Denote the right-hand side of your equation by $f(P).$ Pick a positive starting value for $P$ and then repetitively replace $P$ with $\frac{P + f(P)}{2}$ until the absolute difference between $P$ and $f(P)$ is below your chosen tolerance.

Numerically, you can use the Newton method, which involves considering the function $ f(P) = P - a \log\left(\frac{s + zP}{s + yP}\right) - c $. The Newton method employs the iterative scheme:
$$ P_{n+1} = P_n - \frac{f(P_n)}{f'(P_n)} $$
The sequence $(P_n)$ generated by this scheme converges to a value of $P$ that satisfies the required equality provided that the initial guess is close enough to the unknown zero. There is at least one such $P$, since $f(0) = -c \leq 0 \leq f(\infty)$ and it is continuous.
